# RequireAuthorization() on endpoints.MapControllerRoute() not working and every request passes through

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have the following code in an Asp.Net Core 3.1

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseCors(DefaultCorsPolicyName);

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller}/{action}/{id?}").RequireAuthorization(new AuthorizeAttribute());
    });
}


[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Test()
    {
        return "Test works!";
    }
}
```

but all requests pass through and no authorization works. Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 12):

Add `endpoints.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization(...);` into your endpoint configuration.

Your controller have own/explicit `Route` attribute and is not covered by `MapControllerRoute` call.

Answer (score 1):

Got bitten by this as well, I had a code like this:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
  {
     options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .AddRequirements(new MustBeSuperAdminRequirement())
        .Build();
  })
```

One would be forgiven to think that `MustBeSuperAdminRequirement` won't be called if user has not logged in... **but it is not so**!... it went straight in and I spent a few hours scratching my head...

As a workaround I did this:

```
public static IMvcBuilder ConfigureMvc(this IServiceCollection services)
{
  services
    .AddAuthorization(options =>
     {
        options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        //.RequireAuthenticatedUser()  //<-- this does not seems to do anything, refer: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/4656#issuecomment-605012014
        .AddRequirements(new MustBePtwUserRequirement())
        .Build();
     })
```

```
protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(
            AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
            MustBeSuperAdminRequirement requirement)
{
    var principal = context.User;
    if (!principal.IsAuthenticated())
    {
        return;  //user not logged in
    }

   //the rest of the codes
}
```

.. and here...

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => 
{
    endpoints.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization();
});
```